# Is $3,7 USD for 340 grams/11.9 oz of "creamy" Skippy-brand peanut butter expensive from an American's perspective?

Tags: united-states, price, sweden, cost-of-living

Right now, in Sweden, a small-feeling 340 g (which is apparently 11.9 oz) jar of "Skippy creamy peanut butter" is, translated to current USD value, $3.7 USD. I think it has been around this price for a long time, and it's an expected standard price for something like that, given how much everything costs these days.

However, I have heard economic tips such as "use peanut butter and apple sauce on toast bread", which all seem to imply that this is a cheap and yet filling meal. However, considering how relatively little peanut butter is in such a jar, this sounds like it would quickly get expensive if eaten constantly, with Swedish prices. (And that apple sauce isn't free either...)

Apparently, it's "extra smooth", but I don't know if that is just part of the advertising slogan or actually a separate product, and if so, if this is some kind of unusually pricey version. It's the **only** peanut butter product sold here (except for the "crunchy" version of the same brand).

In the USA, is perhaps a larger can of peanut butter of this quality (whether that is low, medium or high, I cannot tell) far less expensive than my price for the small jar? I suspect this is the case.

Comment: No offense but this seems off topic to me. Also, it's easily answerable through Google or checking a few stores online, for example Walmart or Amazon Fresh

Comment: Can you check the jar for a place of manufacture?  If its made locally, how does that compare to the same size of locally made product?

Comment: to my understanding, the concept of cheap/expensive is quite subjective, so it is hard to come up with an answer to such a question unless you specify how one can assess the cheapness/expensiveness of the mentioned object.

Comment: This question, as it stands, especially the title, is way too specific to the price and quantity to be particularly useful to others with the same question. The more general version of this question would be "how much does peanut butter cost in the US". But phrasing it that way makes it much more clear that it's off topic, as others have pointed out it is. There might also be the question of what others consider expensive, but, as has also been pointed out, this is probably too subjective for this site.

Comment: Is the price you're quoting including or excluding sales tax? That might affect the comparison; I think it's common in the US to advertise and compare prices without sales tax.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because one can trivially check the price of anything, instantly, online. Simply visit any US supermarket web site, say publix.com.  Or, use "google.com" and enter "price of skippy 11oz".

Comment: @marcelm - I can't vouch for all 50 states but in every state that I've been in, there is no sales tax on unprepared food.

Comment: @Fattie - Are you a peanut butter hater?  ;->)

Comment: @Fattie Not quite so trivial. `publix.com` is not available to users outside USA. Even using "google.com", G localises the search these days... I find a bunch of suppliers in local currency that are selling imported goods... wow, 16 USD (equiv) for 16 oz jar - ooomph!

Comment: @BobBaerker - I'm just against the Man gouging CItizens!

Comment: "Extra Creamy" is Skippy's standard labeling.  In the US most peanut butter comes in a smooth (homogeneous) and a crunchy (bits of chopped up peanuts) variety.

Comment: To recast this as on-topic, suggest you restate it in terms of nutrition: how many grams protein/$ you can get, while minimizing grams of saturated fat (and in particular transfat).

Comment: **You specifically picked 11.9 oz, which is a 'convenience size', not the bulk sizes, which are 64oz/4lb and 5lb, which are going to be priced more economically; or twin-packs of 2x48oz** There is a well-known trend in US grocery retailing that 'convenience sizes' are priced at a premium, and you should avoid them if you can buy bulk and store it; this typically works in favor of families, homeowners and people with large houses and vehicles, and against single people/renters.

Comment: This is a "Highly active question."  Who knew that peanut butter is such an integral part of Personal Finance??? ;->)

Comment: @Criggie: when peanuts are locally manufactured in Sweden, we will know for sure that climate change is irreversible(!) [Peanuts are grown in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peanut) southeastern US, West Africa, China, S/SE Asia, Latin America. They're hardly growable at all inside the EU, and [Hungary seems to the most northerly, not Sweden](https://www.atlasbig.com/en-us/countries-peanut-production).

Comment: +1 for giving me peanut-butter cravings.

Comment: At my local ICA, we have 4 different brands of peanut butter. Skippy is the worst of them.

Comment: @0xFEE1DEAD Checking online stores really isn't a good indicator for normal U.S. grocery prices, at least in my experience. I typically find stuff significantly cheaper in-store. Which makes sense, because there's no delivery cost built into the price.

Comment: @reirab the variance between states is a much bigger factor than shipping costs and I don't think asking random strangers for anecdotal evidence is more precise. Again, this site is for personal finance, not econometrics.

Comment: Simple Amazon search shows a range from 12 cents an ounce to 18 or so. Your jar is worth $1.43 - $2.14. Yes, the 5lb (2.27kg) is cheapest per gram.

Answer (score 37):

You've got two or three factors jacking up the price from what you'd pay for peanut butter in the US, which is probably where most of those cheap meal suggestions come from.

First, Skippy is a highly-advertised brand name, so you if you buy it, you are paying for all the advertising.

Second, it's probably not made in Sweden but imported from the US, so you pay shipping costs and maybe import tariffs.

Third, it's been my experience that pretty much all food is more expensive in Europe than in the US.

Edit after visiting the grocery store: For comparison, an 18 oz/510 g jar* of store brand (WinCo) peanut butter* costs $1.64 at my local store.  A close to the same size jar of Skippy Creamy peanut butter was $2.69, so you're paying about twice US price per oz/gram for the same brand, and over three times as much as for the store brand.

*This is the smallest size the store had, of either brand.

Comment: "Third, it's been my experience that pretty much all food is more expensive in Europe than in the US." - This is true for processed foods but I'd say fresh food tends to be cheaper in Europe, as does buying prepared food in restaurants.  Though the latter varies by country/locale and the way the US does tax/tipping makes direct comparisons less straightforward than they should be.

Comment: *Unreferenced footnote error?

Comment: Also, peanut butter is very much a localized cultural product and its consumption in Sweden is minuscule. In US its sales profit comes from volume, in Sweden you have to increase the markup to make importing and sales profitable.

Comment: For peanuts there is also the "US peanut program", which subsidizes USA peanut production and helps keep the prices down (by shifting the cost to tax payers).

Comment: The $1.64 and $2.69, is that before or after sales tax? In Sweden (I believe) the sales tax will be included in the listed price for the item. In the states, sales tax tends to be added at checkout, right?

Comment: @Kialandei It depends on the state; I believe most exclude general grocery items from sales tax

Comment: @anjama Ah yes, that's a fair point. I forgot that food items are often excluded from things like VAT

Comment: @Kialandei Unfortunately not all do exclude it, including my state. It's a regressive tax and should be gotten rid of

Comment: Peanut butter, in particular, is cheaper in the US because the peanuts are almost certainly grown domestically.  The US is the #4 peanut producer in the world, behind China and India, who both consume a lot domestically, and Nigeria, who is the major exporter to the EU.  Skippy will be a US export, though, so not made with Nigerian peanuts.  Still, you can get organic, top shelf peanut butter in Sweden at basically the same price as Skippy, so it's definitely pricier simply because it's a foreign import.  Skippy has no factory in Sweden - there's one in Little Rock AR, and one in Shandong.

Comment: @Kialandei: In my state, there is no sales tax on food (groceries, anyway: restaurant food is taxed), though as others have noted, this varies between states.

Comment: Alcohol was also far cheaper in Europe from my experience.

Comment: @jamesqf almost all food is cheaper here in the Netherlands than in the US. Sweden and the other Nordics are a different matter.

Comment: @Glorfindel: IDK, as I've never been to the Netherlands.  Switzerland, Britain & Ireland, Scandinavia are the only places I've spent long enough to get an idea of grocery prices.  But prices can vary quite a bit between different areas of the US, too.

Comment: @aroth "as does buying prepared food in restaurants" This does not even remotely match my experience, unless by "the US" you mean specifically "SF and NYC." Of the meals I've eaten in France, Switzerland, and Italy, I'd estimate most were 50-100% more expensive than I would normally pay for a comparable meal in the U.S., even after accounting for tax and tip. This is especially true if soft drinks are ordered (I don't drink alcohol, so I don't have much knowledge of how that compares.) Soft drinks in the U.S. also typically include free refills, whereas they typically don't in Europe.

Answer (score 22):

You careened out of your way to pick a bad product on several levels.

- It’s an American name and taste.  Its target market is American expats and others with strong desire for the American “taste”, and so it commands a premium price.
- USA Skippy substitutes cheap oils for the peanut oil, uses HFCS instead of sugar, and uses GMO strains not yet certified in Europe. These and other issues would interfere with it being imported commercially into the EU. To satisfy demand, they (or likely, a partner) makes an EU-legal version flavored to taste about the same.  *That is a limited-run specialty product requiring a higher price*.
- The taste is tuned for Americans’ sugar-heavy palate, which does not appeal to Europeans.  Swedes surely have domestic or EU brands of peanut butter they prefer.  You should price those.

Even in the US, Skippy asks a lot “for the name”.  Target has a 16 ounce jar of Skippy for $2.29, but they also have an equivalent house-brand for $1.29.  Target also has house-brand organics for $4 a jar, either a) stir-it (peanuts only, really), or b) no-stir (like Skippy, but it’s *organic* crud, and the sugar is dialed down to almost zero).  That’s probably comparable to what Swedes eat.

So if you really want Skippy particularly, that’s an expensive choice.  If money is a factor, don’t waste it on name-brands and full-retail groceries. In the US I would send you to Trader Joes or Aldi.  (There may be Aldi there; it is German after all). And of course avail yourself of any government programs.

Also consider that COVID is affecting food supply, and I would think that’s especially true for oddball, import or boutique items.

Certainly your article is right that you can get a lot of food for very little money.   However the advice of some of them is laughable; for instance filthy-rich Gwyneth Paltrow tried to design a month of attractive meals on a monthly food-stamp budget, and somehow had people buying 3 *limes*.

Applesauce seems like one of those; it’s expensive and the picture of empty calories.  Cheap white bread (and “white” food generally) are also empty calories; they taste good but leave you hungry. Simply switching to whole wheat helps a lot: better for you and make you feel full.

Now if they’re going to P.B. for the protein, watch it - protein is not a single substance, it’s a variety, and they must be in the right proportions to be bodily useful, Red meat is ideal, but vegetables require combining in a particular way to get the benefit.  Ask biologists or vegetarians.

Comment: The cheap proteins would be rice&beans. In isolation, both lack some amino acids, but together you get all the essential amino acids at a price much lower than meat.

Comment: Of course, 3 limes and a bit of salt can take you a long way - you do have Cointreau and tequila on stock, don't you?

Comment: What's wrong with buying limes on food stamps? They're cheap enough that you could easily buy them if you watch your budget and they improve the flavor of lots of meals.

Comment: `Americans have a taste for “sugar in everything”` -- Americans have a "taste for sugar in everything" because food manufacturers in the United States *put sugar in everything.*  I have to hunt for spaghetti sauce without sugar (sugar in spaghetti sauce is an abomination).

Comment: @Harper: Did Paltrow try again? Washington Post [has her down](https://www.washingtonpost.com/news/morning-mix/wp/2015/04/17/a-hungry-gwyneth-paltrow-fails-the-food-stamp-challenge-four-days-in/) as _seven_ limes in a _week's_ budget.

Comment: I feel like the way this answer goes out of its way to insult the peanut butter brand (and Americans to some extent) detracts from the answer.

Comment: @aquirdturtle Alright, I toned that down, but there’s no way not to imply that.  It is true, and it’s relevant to the answer.

Comment: Actually, it's recently been decided that protein combining isn't as important as they thought it was, according to the Wikipedia article on protein combining, anyway.  This from the American Heart Association and the American Dietetic Association among others.  The advice is now just not to rely mainly on grains or mainly on beans (or any one other category, e.g. nuts, although those are better) for your protein, but if you have both then you're probably in the clear, and it doesn't have to be at the same meal, just the same day.

Comment: For comparison, here in the UK, the same 340g jars of Skippy's Peanut Butter are sold for the equivalent of $2.96 at Morrisons supermarket - $0.87 per 100g.  (Presumably this is the special EU recipe, since we're still on EU rules at the time I write this).  I don't know why the difference, unless it's that peanut butter is more popular here than in Sweden.  A 340g jar of Morrisons' own-brand, though, is only $1.60 ($0.47 per 100g), with slightly less salt and sugar.  Whole Earth sugar-free (97% peanuts as against 90%) is $0.95 per 100g, or $1.16 per 100g for organic.

Answer (score 7):

I got some peanut butter recently and it was not nearly this expensive, so I took at look at what Walmart had. I found what looks like the exact sort you got for 2.36 USD:

https://www.walmart.com/ip/Skippy-Creamy-Peanut-Butter-12-oz-Jar/191560633

You can find this brand cheaper by weight if you get larger jars or packs with more at a time. I would say 3.7 USD for the same jar is expensive for Skippy, let alone peanut butter in general.

There are also plenty of other options and brands, even in smaller stores. For example, here's a 64 ounce jar of Walmart's house brand for 5 USD:

https://www.walmart.com/ip/Great-Value-Creamy-Peanut-Butter-64-oz/47375932

Comment: And the jars in that four-pack are over 16 oz, which is significantly larger than OP's 340g jar.

Comment: @user34258 I read it at 16 oz originally; no idea where I got that number from. Let me find an equivalent size.

Comment: I'm not even sure you need to; the fact that you can get more for less money makes your point that it tends to be cheaper.

Comment: I see a 3-pack of 16.3 oz jars at Walmart for $7.09

Comment: 1.8kg of peanut butter in one jar!

Answer (score 6):

Others have established that peanut butter is in fact less expensive in the US than in Sweden, and that is the question you explicitly asked. However, the context for your question was advice for eating cheaply. In order for peanut butter to be good advice in the US but not Sweden, the price of peanut butter *relative to what it replaces* would have to be less in the US. Here, 255g of pre-sliced roast turkey is $4. That's about 50% more expensive. I think this is the kind of comparison that the advice you see is making. If you are already cooking dried beans at maybe $1.50 for half a kg, then peanut butter is no bargain at all, in the US or Sweden.

Answer (score 4):

Google tells me that 340g of peanut butter has eactly 2,000 calories. At 3.7 USD, this would be 540 calories per $.

As a comparison, for a 15.5 oz can of beans, there is about 682 calories. Per this Swedish grocery store website, it looks like you can get a can like this for between 8kr-12kr, (https://www.coop.se/globalt-sok/?query=b%C3%B6nor), which is about $.83 USD - $1.2 USD. This equals about 821-568 calories per $.

So peanut butter is about as expensive per calorie as 'higher end' can of beans.  Perhaps you will tell me 'ah yes but beans are notoriously expensive in Sweden', at which point I shrug my shoulders. Peanut butter is cheap-ish in Sweden as a pure calorie source, but perhaps not the absolutely least expensive option possible.

Answer (score 2):

$3.70 for an 11.9 oz jar  is expensive.  Where I live in the USA, a 16 oz jar costs a bit under $3.00

For most of my life I didn't care much for peanut butter.  Then about 8 years ago a switch flipped and now, honey roasted creamy peanut butter is one of my biggest food vices.  I like it in my protein shakes, on top of a protein bar, even straight up.  The one thing that didn't work was peanut butter in my coffee.  It's not miscible so I ended up with a bottom layer of molten peanut butter in my coffee cup! :-O

The 40 oz jars are much more cost efficient at a cost of $6 to $7  each.  And given that it's a frequent buy one/get one free sale item, that further cuts the price in half.

Generic peanut butters are even less expensive but I'm kind of particular when it comes to molten peanut butter ;->)

Comment: This suggests that the shipping cost to Sweden from the plant in the US, plus all import/export taxes tarrifs and duties is about $1-2 USD.  That's not bad, all things considered.

Comment: @Criggie: As another answer notes; it's likely not from a US plant as the American product would never meet EU food quality requirements. It's likely a low-volume product made in the EU.

Comment: As an alternative to PBJ sandwiches I added PB and jam into a bowl of oatmeal. Works nicely and less messy too.

Answer (score 1):

At a bulk store such as Costco 2x 48oz (total 2.72kg) Jif or Skippy cheap brands cost about USD 10 so about 37 cents/100g, less on sale. No particular difference in price for creamy vs chunky.

Your price is 1.09/100g, so about 3x in nominal terms. Comparing the [Big Mac Index](https://www.statista.com/statistics/274326/big-mac-index-global-prices-for-a-big-mac/), seems it is also similarly expensive in purchasing power terms.

That said, I don’t think it’s out of line for a small jar, perhaps purchased at a specialty store or a convenience store.

Mass-market peanut butter and (perhaps more importantly) low quality mass-market bread are very cheap in North America, so they make a meal that meets some nutritional requirements at low cost. Eggs are super-cheap protein as well, I’ve seen 20 cents total for 3 eggs in packs of 90 (though the production conditions are likely pretty horrific).

Personally, I pay (in Canada) similar to US price for peanut butter ~USD0.30/100g in a 2kg jar, but about USD 0.40 for two slices of artisanal bread, so a PB&J sandwich is probably in the US 1.00 range. If I used cheap bread and cheap jam it could be half that.

Anything that counts as a meal and is in the $1 range seems cheap to me- that is 1/2 or 1/3 average US spending (and there are many folks living on very low incomes in the US).

If you start adding requirements such as ‘organic’, prices can easily skyrocket since there are many, many people who can afford to pay a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

A quick search for the price of a jar of peanut butter from Price Chopper (a common grocery store in America) shows a 16 oz jar of peanut butter can cost anywhere from $3.19 for Skippy (Actually 16.3 oz), or as low as $1.99 for store brand.

https://shop.pricechopper.com/shop/categories/92

These are *not* the only factors in deciding that peanut butter is an economic food though.

Consider also the cost of a jar of jam, which from the same search can go as low as $2.49 for 18 oz (assuming you don't want the even cheaper $1.99 jelly, which can be a little gross)

And for bread, a single loaf can be anywhere from $4.49 for high quality stuff, to $1.29 for the extremely cheap store-brand stuff.

https://shop.pricechopper.com/shop/categories/89

Even with the higher quality ingredients, if you add up $4.49, $2.49, and $3.19, you get $10.17.

For ingredients that can make around 8 to 10 sandwiches, depending on how many slices of bread you get in a loaf (and whether or not you use the heels of the bread).

So the real reason peanut butter is considered a 'cheap' food source isn't just the exact price, but the fact that it can be used multiple times with other relatively low-cost ingredients.

If you were to use the cheaper ingredients, the price for 10 of these sandwiches would be a mere $5.27.

Answer (score 0):

**You specifically picked 11.9 oz, which is a 'convenience size', not the bulk sizes, which are going to be priced more economically: 64oz/4lb and 5lb and twin-packs of 2x48oz**

There is a well-known trend in US grocery retailing that 'convenience sizes' are priced at a premium, and you should avoid them if you can buy in bulk and store it (CostCo, Amazon, Walmart/Sam's Club, Smart & Final); this typically works in favor of families, homeowners and people with large houses and cars/minivans, and against single people/renters/people who have to share cupboards/fridges/freezers / people who live alone/convenience users.

If you plot the $/oz for prices from Amazon or Google Shopping for [Skippy peanut butter](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=skippy+peanut+butter&i=grocery&ref=nb_sb_noss_2), you will get a markedly non-linear curve: small sizes are uneconomical, larger are far better value.

Comment: You really have to watch 'em like a hawk. I've caught my local store pricing the bulk-sized containers *higher* on a per-unit basis that the convenience sizes. I suspect their rationale is that people *assume* that the larger sizes are cheaper per unit, so they raise the prices on the larger sizes to make more money.

Comment: @Bob Jarvis - Reinstate Monica: OTOH, sometimes my usual store (WinCo) has the larger size of something priced lower than the smaller size.  Not less per oz/gm (which you would expect), but less for the package.  Go figure...

Answer (score 0):

This is, in my opinion, a very high price. At our local Sam's Club (discount "warehouse" store - sells larger quantities at (sometimes) lower prices - but not always - I've learned to watch them like a hawk and compare-compare-compare to my local supermarket) 96 ounces (2.72 kg) of Skippy creamy peanut butter is priced at $8.98.

Your 11.9 oz container at $3.70 comes out to about 31 cents-per-ounce.

The larger quantity (96 oz) at $8.98 comes out to about 9 cents-per-ounce.

Answer (score 0):

I live in the U.S.  My family likes peanut butter.  We bought some just yesterday at Whole Foods Markets (owned by Amazon). WFM is a grocery store chain that emphasizes "healthy" food, although not everything they sell is "organic". I know they have some European presense, but I'm not sure about Sweden.

A WFM store typically has at least 3 grinding machines that look like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lIFGIj6ma4g (someone's old YouTube video)

The usual choices are: organic peanuts, conventional (not organic) peanuts, and almonds. You press a button, the machine grinds its contents as you watch, and dispenses the fresh paste into a container. They are sold by weight. We paid $5.19 per pound of organic peanut butter (there's no sales tax, VAT, etc). That translates to $0.011442 per gram or $3.89 for 340 grams.  Non-organic would have been a little cheaper.

I made me a sandwich earlier today that used maybe a tablespoon and a half of peanut butter - maybe $0.20 worth.

So, it sounds like the prices are comparable between WHM and your store, and given how "dense" it is, I don't think it's expensive.

As other answerers noted, there's a world of difference between freshly ground peanut butter (we try to eat it within a couple of weeks, otherwise it separates) and peanut butter in a jar. Not to pick on Skippy brand, but since you mentioned it, here are the ingredients:

[image]

It contains:

- roasted peanuts - good, that's what we want
- sugar - even if we assume it's real sugar from beets or cane, and not some kind of high-fructose corn syrup, there's no need to add any sweetener to peanut butter. The peanuts taste better without any sweetener.
- hydrogenated vegetable oil (cottonseed, soybean, rapeseed, or palm oil) - I prefer to avoid hydrogenated oil.
- salt - again, there's no reason to add salt to peanut butter.

As other mentioned, the label warns that it "may" contain GMO. I'm not paranoid about GMO, but I know there are [no GMO peanuts](https://www.nationalpeanutboard.org/wellness/mythbusters-gmo-peanuts.htm) on the market, so they must refer to the hydrogenated vegetable oil added to extend its shelf life.

My advice to you is to avoid peanut butter in a jar if you can find it fresh instead. It does taste better.